# The [collision] tag is often misused despite the description indicating how to use it correctly. What should we do about it?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, clean-up

The tag [collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision) has the following wiki excerpt:

> The intersection of one or more objects or concepts, such as communications packets or function names. For questions about collision detection (in computer graphics) use the [collision-detection] tag instead.

and full tag wiki:

> May be used to describe graphical elements (as in a game setting), networking (when multiple packets arrive at the same location simultaneously), RF communication when transmissions overlap and interrupt one another or in programming when disparate functions have similar naming conventions (see also [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namespace)).
>
> For questions about collision detection (in computer graphics) use [collision-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection) instead.

It explicitly states that the tag [collision-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection) should be used instead for questions about collision detection rather than naming collisions, however looking at the uses of [collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision) it looks like a lot of the time, possibly even the majority of its uses, it is misused when [collision-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection) should be used instead. It is often used for questions about collision detection in games or physics simulations.

How should we resolve this? There are probably useful legitimate uses of this tag, but it seems to be prone to be misused. Maybe just the description should be changed to say that it should not be confused with [collision-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection) right at the beginning or even in caps. I can see that even if they read part of the description, "The intersection of one or more objects or concepts" could still be misinterpreted as referring to collision detection. Or do you think that this tag will still be misused no matter the description?

Comment: "such as communications packets or function names" That seems like having a tag for things such as rocket science or cuddling horses. Is it used consistently at all, outside of being "misused" for collision-detection?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't think we want a tag that can be compared to topics that are out of the scope of the site.

Comment: @Braiam My (flippant) point was that the two scope examples "communications packets" and "function names" are nothing alike – which makes them somewhat useless to define the scope.

Comment: In addition, there is already [tag:name-collision]: *within the context of computers and computer programming, "name collision" is the technical term for an instance in which two items have the same name within some logical enclosure*.  And also: [tag:hash-collision], [tag:jquery-collision] Not sure I'm seeing any value for [tag:collision] at this point, although a tag for packet collision looks reasonable if there is a decent number of questions.

Comment: You've focused on the wiki excerpt, apparently without even knowing that there was a longer description: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/collision/info   Note that the longer description explicitly encourages use for graphical objects.  I agree with the others that say this tag is terrible and needs to disappear entirely.

Comment: (Hovering over a tag displays the excerpt (and [some tag wiki excerpts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino) go all caps). But not in an edit view, only the ["normal" view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913390/basic-arduino-serial-communication). Is there a technical reason?)

Comment: @BenVoigt: The long description is self-contradictory — one part says "yes, graphics collisions OK" and a later part says "no, do not use for graphics collisions".  It mentions the [tag:namespaces] tag rather than [tag:name-collisions].

Comment: I so want to tag this question collision.

Comment: *Maybe just the description should be changed to say...* - we even have tags that have a description starting with DO NOT USE,  but that doesn't stop a large number of users from using. Unfortunately only site curators seem to care about the tag description. The list of wrongly used tags is long.

Comment: Related, horrible tag found when checking up this one: [tag:motion].

Comment: @BenVoigt (and OP), the correct fix is to edit it so that the **pop-up** that is shown (the excerpt) explains the usage in the **first** sentence - I've edited [tag:collision-detection] as per MSE FAQ. It will need to be approved before it's visible, and possibly re-edited (hint).

Comment: Well, I tried but it says the queue is full; so a privileged user will have to do the edit. My suggestion for the excerpt is: "In computer games graphics, object collision detection is the problem of determining if geometric objects intersect. It is an important topic in computer graphics, in CAD/CAM, in dynamical simulation, and in computer games.".

Comment: @Rob: While that's true, "collision detection" means much more.  Did you read Lundin's excellent answer?  Just to be explicit, CSMA/CD is "Carrier Sense Multiple Access with **Collision Detection**".

Comment: @BenVoigt, that's not an "object". It's already tagged as straight [collision](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CSMA%2FCD&searchOn=3) or without that tag. --- You are free to edit the Wiki as you wish; note that I said possibly re-edited, improvements welcome. I see that commenting to me four hours ago is more important than [simply fixing the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/collision-detection/info), thanks!

Comment: Burnination requests are supposed to be punny. Them's the rules. E.g. "_No [collision]-waivers for this tag!_" or "_A [collision] of ambiguous meanings_"

Comment: @Rob: I didn't say it involved objects.  I said "Collision Detection" is much broader than your narrow definition focused on geometric objects.  As Lundin said "collision-detection" is not any less ambiguous than "collision" itself.

Comment: @Ben and I said "collision" covers the case of your example. The definition of [collision-detection] is resolved at  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/collision-detection/info & https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/collision-detection/info - it's limited to objects, meeting of the minds isn't. Network and namespace collisions aren't physical collisions, it's like arguing that a cheque or credit card is the same as cash, that cryptocurrency is as good as gold - it's possible to have similarities without equality. Much like a business can have a sign "Cash Only", we can limit our definition.

Answer (score 26):

This tag is ambiguous and should get removed, not renamed. It can mean/is being used as any of the following:

- Network collisions, as in packet collisions in networks designed with  CSMA/CD or CSMA/CA.
- Algorithm collisions, as in duplicate indices in some data container type or database.
- Namespace collisions, as in declaring the same identifier multiple times in source code.
- Graphical collisions, as in determining if/when two drawn graphical objects collide with each other. The majority of them seems to be about the Unity framework.
- Physical collisions, as in detecting if an embedded system is physically colliding with something using accelerometers, or about the physics theory involved in it.

"Collision-detection" would not really clarify anything or make the tag less ambiguous.

---

Burnination criteria:

- > Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  No, see above. It is very ambiguous.
- > Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  In some cases on-topic, in other cases off-topic.
- > Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  No.
- > Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  No, see above.

Comment: Forgot hash collisions.

Comment: @user3840170 No. Those are a form of algorithm collisions.

Comment: "Graphical collisions" — what an unintuitive way to put it when objects can collide non-graphically  1) off screen 2) off frame, through interpolation, and 3) with invisible objects; and they don't always collide when even they "visually collide" in the same way that the sun has never collided with the moon during a solar eclipse. I think a better term for this is "collision geometry".

Comment: ""Collision-detection" would not really clarify anything or make the tag less ambiguous." `Collision detection` is in my mind unambiguously referring to graphical (well, physical, but in the physics-engine sense rather than the real-world-tangible-object sense) collision. Network/algo/namespace collisions wouldn't ordinarily benefit from being detected (you try to avoid them as much as possible, and it's obvious when they do happen); graphical collisions are supposed to happen, knowing that they happened is relevant to the code and there's an entire theory behind it.

Comment: As for physical collision as you describe it, surely that's off topic here?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Although you may personally never use "Collision Detection" for networking, network engineers do.  CSMA/CD is "Carrier Sense Multiple Access with **Collision Detection**"

Comment: @Laurel The purpose of this post is not to educate users of meta about collision theory or to be technically correct. We have stackoverflow.com for that. It might however be of importance to note that the majority of those questions seem to be related to Unity.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Network collisions is a whole topic of it's own. It's a fundamental part of understanding Ethernet and TCP/IP, as well as CAN bus. The protocol/application layers of various such data communication buses have always been on-topic here. As for physical collisions with accelerometers, the software/algorithm/interfacing part is on-topic here, sorting under embedded systems. Designing or trouble-shooting the electronics hardware is off-topic though. I only (at a glance) found one single post about accelerometers though.